# openerp odoo v11.0 invalid model name error

Tags: module, odoo

i am trying to build an odoo module named kroshu for stock managment 
i have wrote the needed models and the views 
after i try to install my module odoo server shows this message

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 11.0\server\odoo\addons\base\ir  \ir_actions.py", line 128, in _check_model
  raise ValidationError(_('Invalid model name %r in action definition.')  % action.res_model)
   odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Invalid model name 'kroshu.product' in  action definition.
    None" while parsing file:/c:/program%20files%20(x86)/odoo%2011.0/server/odoo/addons/kroshu_khalil_kasmi/data/actions.xml:5, near
```

```xml
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_kroshu_product">
       <field name="name">Product</field>
       <field name="res_model">kroshu.product</field>
       <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```

my module is named Product.py :

```py
from odoo import models,fields

class Product(models.Model):
    _name = 'kroshu.product'

    product_id = fields.Char("product id",required =True)
    product_name = fields.Char("product name",required = True)
    product_description = fields.text("product description")

    product_type =  fields.One2many("product.type","product_type_id",string="type")
    product_category = fields.One2many("product.category","product_category_id",string="category")

    quantity_on_hand = fields.Integer("quantity on hand",required =True)
    forcasted_quantity = fields.Integer("forcasted quantity")

    location_in_stock = fields.Char("product location in stock")

    barcode = fields.text("barcode")

    vendor = fields.One2many("product.vendor","vendor_id",string="vendor/manufacturer")

    cost = fields.Float("cost")

    stock = fields.One2many("kroshu.stock","stock_id",string="in stock")
```

my action_views.xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
<menuitem name="Kroshu" id="kroshu_root_menu"/>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_kroshu_product">
    <field name="name">Product</field>
    <field name="res_model">kroshu.product</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_kroshu_product_category">
    <field name="name">Product Category</field>
    <field name="res_model">product.category</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>
........ still more lines
```

my  __ init __ .py file :

```py
from . import category
from . import product
```

Comment: Can you tell if the interpreter is compiling Product.py? You should find a Product.pyc file if it is being processed.

Comment: It may be just a formatting thing here in stack overflow however the indentation appears off on your Product.py file as well. I will ammend it.

Comment: You mention your file is called `Product.py` however in your __init__.py file you import `product`. You may want to ensure your `Product.py` file is in fact `product.py` to ensure it is imported properly.

Answer (score 1):

From what you have stated above. The issue is likely that in your `__init__.py` file you are importing `product` however the file is called `Product.py`. I also am not sure of the indentation within `Product.py` however this may just be formatting of what was copied and pasted into stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error inside your model definition:

```
barcode = fields.text("barcode")
```

instead of :

```
barcode = fields.Text("barcode")
```

change text to Text and your code 'll become nice.

Second Solution:
try to rename your model name, change

```
_name = 'kroshu.product'
```

for example like:

```
_name = 'kroshuproduct'
```

Odoo commonly uses this expression to specify that the model ***product*** is inside de module name ***kroshup*** for example.

> This error mostly occur when you have and error inside your Model
>   definition. to detect your Error, comment all fields and test every
>   fields alone.

Hope this help you! Great!

Comment: There is one more occurrence for product_description

Comment: You can use many occurences of your fields model inside the view, but with only one definition in the model's file.

Comment: Yes. I meant that there is another occurrence of the lowercase `.text` in the code: `product_description = fields.text("product description")` This needs to be corrected, too.

Answer (score 0):

When writing a new module, for debugging the general setup, it may help to simplify first and then add step by step, keeping things working.

In your case, first create one model with one field (like `name`) and get that to work. Then, add more simple fields, a view and an action. Make sure you can create records for your new model.

Then, adding relational fields, make sure to include the dependencies in the manifest file where the target models are (in your case, `product` for `product. product` etc.)

Finally, make sure your second model `kroshu.stock` needs to exist, too, following the same methodology.